# Does the asyc\await syntax resolve chained functions?

Tags: javascript, async-await

In this example, if the function was run, would both promises get resolved before `foo` is return ?

```
async function() {
    var foo = await iReturnAPromise().iReturnAPromiseUnrelatedToMyParent();
    return foo;
}
```

Comment: It would, though `iReturnAPromiseUnrelatedToMyParent` doesn't make much sense - did you want `Promise.all`?

Comment: I'm trying to debug existing code that uses this pattern. I may well have to refactor using promise all. But for now, I'm just trying to understand where the existing problem lies.

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `await (await iReturnAPromise()).iReturnAPromiseUnrelatedToMyParent()`?

Comment: @WiktorZychla, yes, you're right, though it might depend... Here, if the `Promise` implementation does not have a `iReturnAPromiseUnrelatedToMyParent` method, the OP will get a runtime error. If `Promise` does have sucha  method, it would depend on the implementation, what it does ... But well, as a general response I'd say that no, what the OP expects won't work.

Comment: If `iReturnAPromise` *actually* returns a Promise, then it will not have the property `iReturnAPromiseUnrelatedToMyParent`. If `iReturnAPromise` *resolves* to an object which has the property `iReturnAPromiseUnrelatedToMyParent`, then you would have to use `await` twice, once to resolve the first promise to a value, and once to resolve the second promise. (or, since it's an `async` function, you could just return the second promise - the `async` function will return a promise regardless, after all) But that seems to contradict the name `UnrelatedToMyParent`

Comment: Maybe `iReturnAPromiseUnrelatedToMyParent` should have been `iReturnAPromiseThatIsNotDependantOnMyParentToResolve`. The object returned by `iReturnAPromise` is thenable but also contains other objects such as `iReturnAPromiseUnrelatedToMyParent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo` as it is, can only carry one resolution. You may do like

```
foo = await iReturnAPromise().then(v => (doSomeThingWith(v), iReturnAPromiseUnrelatedToMyParent()));
```

in which case `foo` will be assigned the resolution of `iReturnAPromiseUnrelatedToMyParent`. However if you would like to access both resolutions (which are independent of each other) then you may do like;

```js
async function test(){
    [foo,bar] = await Promise.all([Promise.resolve(10), Promise.resolve(20)]);
    return [foo,bar];
}

test().then(([a,b]) => console.log(a,b));
```